# Best way of logging REST API response time in spring + tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, logging

I'm using spring mvc with tomcat servlet container for web services and want to log response time(total execution time) of APIs, so is there any spring service or what is the best way to log such information related to api execution time at spring controller level.

Comment: I would use a servlet filter. I would consider extending a [AbstractRequestLoggingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html).

Comment: I agree with @EdwinDalorzo we can write custom filter which always gets executed first, and logs the response time when request is completed

Answer (score 1):

as the number of views is increasing and there is no proper answer of this post so I thought to answer my finding. So there are two ways if you are using Spring and tomcat.

**Method 1#**

Implement an interceptor and add current time in a new parameter(*requestReceivingTime*) in request `preHandle` block and log the subtraction of *current time* and *requestReceivingTime* in `postHandle` block.

**Method 2#**

You can use tomcat access log to log the request time, you have to edit your `conf/server.xml` and change the format according to your need. for exp

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i , %t Bytes sent: [%B] , Time taken millis: [%D] , Time taken seconds: [%T]  &quot;%r&quot; %s" />
```

**Note :** Pattern could be change in your case, it depends on tomcat version.

Hope this will help !